# foreign key in database

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

i am using linq to sql .dbml ,

May i know what is the best way to add foreign key constraint to the database?
`ALTER TABLE Staffs
 Add CONSTRAINT fk_Staffs FOREIGN KEY(UserId) REFERENCES Users(Id);`

i can write this with no problem. But when my database table increases, i have hard time to maintain the Add Constraint foreign script . Each time when i have multiple update to the database columns, then i will crack my head to update those alter table script.

Could there be a simple process for this? In the .dbml, i can drag and drop the association to add the foreign key, i wonder is there a way that i can export those foreign key into script which like what i wrote above? this is good when i want to do the deployment.

Or must i write the alter script and update it whenever there is changes on tables?
please advice

Comment: What kind of databse are you using?

Comment: I don't quite understand: you need to apply this command **once** to your database and then you should be done with it....

Comment: i am using MSsql. Yes, but what if the database column name is changed? you surely need to go to the alter script to update the column..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to do this once per database update that actually changes a FK relationship.
In the context of doing a database refactoring this is usually not a big deal of the whole refactoring.

But if you don't like writing your scripts you can use the table designer i SQL Management Studio.

1. Right click table -> Design
2. Right click on the appropritate database column (one of the rows in the designer) -> Relationships
3. In the dialog, add a new relationship and select related tables and columns in the properties editor.
4. Done.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way to do it. You can also do it in the designer as written in another answer here but that way if you have to promote from development to production you must do it all by hand and that is very tedious and can easilly lead to errors.

A compromise can be to use the designer to do the changes and in SQL management studio use the right mouse click and select `Script object...´. Than you do not have to type that much.

You mention a change of table names. Well, that should not happen that often!

If it happens a lot, I advise you to create some naming conventions with your team about how to name your columns (and stick to them) and the amount of work will be limited.